# How do I pull variables from an array in order to use those to within my query parameters? I'm using T-SQL in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, iteration

I'm creating a query for my work involving running a query then using the results of that query within an iteration through the dbs of our system. I'm trying to beak this down into a few needed components.

1. Run query that will get the dataset to be iterated through
2. Begin an loop that will run 1 time for each result from the first query.
3. Each time the loop runs it will make a query into a database. The name of the DB will be changed each time by a variable taken from the first dataset and the results will all be appended into a single table or result.
4. With each iteration of the loop change a variable into the ID of each item within the results being iterated through.

I'm not very familiar with setting up loops or variables in SQL and am having trouble understanding it.

This is running in SQL Server Management Studio.

This is what I've figured out so far: the code starts off making a select statement in order to find all the names of the databases that I'll need to iterate through. There are two status codes that when it is that status the table is to be iterated through for its item numbers and its size.

The second select statement grabs all the information that will need to be converted and puts it into a table. The loop would begin before this query then run it multiple times, using the ids of each result from the first table as the name of the db to be queried.

```
/* This is the code I have so far. I'll explain what I'm doing and thinking in the comments*/

/* In this first select statement I'm finding all the databases that 
   will need to be iterated through. I figure I can pull the names, 
   create a table or array that contains them then run the iteration 
   once per item in the array using the DB name as a variable that will 
   change with each iteration */

select *
from edds.eddsdbo.[Case]
where statuscodeartifactid like 178079 
   or StatusCodeArtifactID like 103428

/* Once this first statement has been run I will now I have a 
   number column that is the artificatID. Each database has an area that is 
   titled [EDDS'artifactID']. So if the artifactID = 1111111,
   then the DB would be accessed at [EDDS1111111] */

Drop Table #temptable

/* If the temptable has been created before this drops the table 
   so the operation can be run again and refill the table.*/

/* This select statement pulls the information that will be placed 
   into the temptable. This second statement should be inside the loop. 
   One time for each DB that appeared in the first query's results. */

SELECT 
    [DestinationWorkspace],
    [TotalItems], [FilesSize],
    CAST(LEFT(FilesSize, PATINDEX('%[0-9-.][^0-9-.]%', FilesSize )) AS MONEY) AS Filenumber,
    LTRIM(RIGHT(FilesSize, LEN(FilesSize) - PATINDEX('%[a - z]%', FilesSize ))) AS Unit
INTO
    #temptable
/* The 'from' portion of the statement is where I'll be needing to put 
   in the artifactID variable. Where it says [EDDS1111111] I'd like to 
   be able to have to say [EDDS@variable] where that variable is 
   whatever the artifactID is of that particular round of iteration*/
FROM 
    [EDDS1111111].[EDDSDBO].[JobHistory]
WHERE
    ItemsTransferred > 0 
    AND Overwrite = 'Append Only' 
    AND endtimeutc > '2019-03-31'

/* After the above statement has been run multiple times and 
   appended all queries into the temp table the final select statement 
   does some math on the entire table and converts the values into the 
   desired units.*/

select 
    DestinationWorkspace, TotalItems,
    case
       when right([Unit], 2) = 'KB'
          then FileNumber / 1024 / 1024
       when right([Unit], 2) = 'MB'
          then FileNumber / 1024
       else FileNumber
    end as 'Gigs'
from 
    #temptable
```

Right now the above code works fine but I need to figure out how to put the iteration around the middle statement and create then set the variable to change with each iteration to be the id of the entry that is being iterated over in the first table.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: When you say SQL Server 12, do you mean SQL Server 2012 or version 12 (SQL Server 2014?)

Comment: It's actually SQL Management Studio 18 I just looked at the wrong thing when I put up the title. I corrected it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question of what version of SQL Server though. SSMS 2018 can be used against SQL Server 2008 to 2019, so it actually made it less clear.

Comment: I just double checked. It's SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your database or the column names (hence I've just guessed at the database name column) but here is how I would structure the looping mechanism. The query example below only populates the database engine name however it could be extended to populate the database and table names.

```
/*check if the #databases table is already present and then drop it*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#databases', 'U') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #databases;
end

 select 
                * into #databases
                from edds.eddsdbo.[Case]
                where statuscodeartifactid like 178079 or StatusCodeArtifactID like 103428



            /*Once this first statement has been run I will now I have a 
number column that is the artificatID. Each database has an area that is 
titled [EDDS'artifactID']. So if the artifactID = 1111111 then the DB would 
be accessed at [EDDS1111111]*/

declare @runs int = 1; /*this will track the number of times you iterate over the result set*/
declare @max int = 0; /*this will be the limit*/
declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''; /*this will allow you to dynamically populate the sql*/
declare @databasename sysname='' /*this will allow you to populate each database name*/

select @max=count(*) from #databases;
 /*the limit is now the number of databases inserted in to this table*/

/*check if your temp table exists and drop if neccessary*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #temptable;
end
/*create the temp table as you won't be able to use select into on each loop as your table will already exist on the second loop*/
create table #temptable 
(
    DestinationWorkSpace nvarchar(150),
    TotalItem nvarchar(30),
    Filesize int,
    FileNumber money
);

while @runs<=@max
begin



            /*If the temptable has been created before this drops the table 
so the operation can be run again and refill the table.*/



            /*This select statement pulls the information that will be placed 
into the temptable. This second statment should be inside the loop. One time 
for each DB that appeared in the first query's results.*/
/*begin the loop by assigning your dsatabase name, I don't know what the column is called so I have just called it databasename for now*/
select top 1 @databasename = databasename from #databases;
/*generate your sql using the @databasename variable, if you want to make the database and table names dynamic too then you can use the same formula*/
select @sql=N' insert #temptable (DestinationWorkspace, TotalItems, FileSize, FileNumber)
            SELECT 
                  [DestinationWorkspace]
                  ,[TotalItems] 
                     ,[FilesSize]
                 ,CAST(LEFT(FilesSize, PATINDEX(''%[0-9-.][^0-9-.]%'', FilesSize )) AS 
            money) as Filenumber,
                        LTRIM(RIGHT(FilesSize, LEN(FilesSize) - PATINDEX(''%[a - z]%'', FilesSize ))) As Unit
                         into #temptable FROM ['+cast(@databasename as nvarchar(128))+'].[EDDSDBO].[JobHistory]
              where ItemsTransferred > 0 and Overwrite = ''Append Only'' and endtimeutc > ''2019-03-31''';
/*execute the sql*/
    exec (@sql);
/*remove that row from the databases table so you don't re-do that row*/
delete from #databases where databasename=@databasename;

            /* The 'from' portion of the statement is where I'll be needing to put in the artifiactID variable. Where it says [EDDS1111111] I'd like to 
be able to have to say [EDDS@variable] where that variable is whatever the 
artifactID is of that particular round of iteration*/


/*end the loop*/
select @runs=@runs+1;
end

            /* After the above statement has been run multiple times and 
appended all queries into the temp table the final select statement does some
 math on the entire table and converts the values into the desired units.*/

              select DestinationWorkspace, TotalItems,
                        case
                         when right([Unit],2) = 'KB'
                         then FileNumber/1024/1024
                         when right([Unit],2) = 'MB'
                         then FileNumber/1024
                         else FileNumber
                         end as 'Gigs'
              from #temptable
```